Code coverage report is not generated in sonarqube
I can see the coverage percentage in pipeline but the coverage report is not generated. I think the path given is wrong, can anyone please help in giving correct path and folder for generating code coverage report for angular application
I have given the path in pipeline and also made changes to sonar-properties file

Can you share your logs here? Is this JS/TS LCOV report? Look for Sensor JavaScript/TypeScript Coverage and share that section of your logs for us to help you.
